# matlab: how to find the largest zero of a function in an interval

Tags: matlab, optimization

Given a scalar function handle `f(x)` defined in a closed interval `[a, b]`, I wish to find the largest zero, i.e. the large value `x` in `[a,b]` s.t. `f(x)=0`.

It seems `fzero()` does not support functions defined in close intervals, so starting it from `fzero(f, b)` leads to an error.

So I use `fminbnd()` with the function `g=@(x) (f(x)).^2` but it does not support "initial condition" of `x=b` or otherwise biasing it toward the largest zero...

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, `fzero()` *does* support closed intervals, except the output values for the intervals must have different signs. So it may or may not work, depending on your function.

[Documentation:](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html#btoc6lj-1-x0)

> Initial value, specified as a real scalar or a 2-element real vector...
>
> **2-element vector** — **fzero checks that fun(x0(1)) and fun(x0(2)) have opposite signs, and errors if they do not.** It then iteratively shrinks the interval where fun changes sign to reach a solution. An interval x0 must be finite; it cannot contain ±Inf.

With that said, a quick and dirty way of finding any zero crossing I like to use, is using the `sign()`, `diff()`, and `find()` functions:

```
x = -10:10; % Any interval you want
y = func(x); % Evaluate your function
d = diff(sign(y)); % Change in signs. Any non-zero values are the places (near) zero crossings
ind = find(d); % Get indices of all non-zero values
xz = x(ind); % Get x's near/at zero crossings.
```

You can find the largest x where f(x) = 0 by simply choosing from the biggest `xz`.

Now obviously, this will only give you a crude approximation, and may not be ideal depending on your task; but choose a fine enough interval to test and it should work.

Or, you can use the results of this as a starting point, and find precise values with more advanced numerical algorithms like the [Newton-Raphson method.](https://aaronschlegel.me/newtons-method-equation-roots.html)